# warning #3180: unrecognized OpenMP #pragma

Tags: openmp, intel, icc

I am having a really hard time in implementing openMP code on my mac machine on Terminal with icc compiler. I find the following error! Please do help me with the correction of error.

The following code is pasted as follows. IT NEVER WORK FOR openMP for, reduce either. The pragma is just not recognising. Appreciate yourself trying the code to help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel for
  {
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
        printf("Hello");
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The extra pair of '{' and '}' is your problem, although the compiler should treat that as an error rather than a warning. Did you specific `-qopenmp` or `-fopenmp` as the compiler flags?

Comment: Always make sure to include the full verbatim error message in the question, as well as a clear description how you compile the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to my comment, the correct version of the code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
        printf("Hello");
      }
  return 0;
}
```

The proper compiler command line is `icc -fopenmp ... -o bla.exe bla.c` (assuming that the file is named `bla.c`).  Please replace `...` with the other command line options that you will need for your code to compile.

UPDATE: The proper compiler command line for the new OpenMP compilers from Intel is to use -fiopenmp (needs -fopenmp-targets=spir64 for GPUs).

Comment: warning #3180: unrecognized OpenMP #pragma                    #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+ : sum) map(tofrom:sum) Similar error unrecognised pragma. What do you say?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Is it ICC or ICX?

Comment: icpx. Problem fixed.